# ARM Template for VM creation in an existing Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a vm in an existing virtual network in the same subscription using ARM Template, If i try to create with the microsoft provided document, it is creating one more virtual network, Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from the below example present at GitHub.

It deploy a single VM with a new or existing Virtual Network, Storage and Public IP using Conditions. You can modify this ARM Template according to your requirements.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-new-or-existing-conditions